# Searching for advanced regex patterns with kwic()

Tags: r, regex, quanteda

I want to use kwic() to find patterns in text with more advanced regex phrases, but I am struggling with the way kwic() is tokenising phrases and two problems evolved:

**1) How to use grouping with phrases that contain whitespace:**

```
kwic(text, pattern = phrase("\\b(address|g[eo]t? into|gotten into)\\b \\bno\\b"), valuetype="regex")
```

> Error in stri_detect_regex(types_search, pattern, case_insensitive = case_insensitive) :
>    Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)

**2) How to look for a longer sequence of words** (similar to the first question) :

```
kwic("this is a test", pattern= phrase("(\\w+\\s){1,3}"), valuetype="regex", remove_separator=FALSE)
```

> kwic object with 0 rows

```
kwic("this is a test", pattern= phrase("(\\w+ ){0,2}"), valuetype="regex", remove_separator=FALSE)
```

> Error in stri_detect_regex(types_search, pattern, case_insensitive = case_insensitive) : 
>     Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to understand with `phrase()` is that it makes it possible to create sequences of patterns, delimited by whitespace, as a single character value.  It should not, at least for normal usage, include the whitespace delimiters as part of the pattern.

I've chosen a reproducible example for the **first part of your question**, which I think illustrates the point and answers your question.

Here, we simply put the different patterns into `phrase()` with a space between them.  This is equivalent to wrapping them inside a `list()`, and making the sequence of separate patterns into elements of a character vector.

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 2.0.1

kwic("a b c a b d e", pattern = phrase("b c|d"), valuetype = "regex")
#>                                      
#>  [text1, 2:3]       a | b c | a b d e
#>  [text1, 5:6] a b c a | b d | e
kwic("a b c a b d e", pattern = list(c("b", "c|d")), valuetype = "regex")
#>                                      
#>  [text1, 2:3]       a | b c | a b d e
#>  [text1, 5:6] a b c a | b d | e
```

We could also consider a vector of sequence matches, including with very inclusive matches, such as the `".+ ^a$"` below matching any sequence of 1 or more characters, followed by the token `"a"`.  Notice how the `^$` makes it explicit that this is the start and end of the (single-token) regex.

```r
kwic("a b c a b d e", pattern = phrase(c("b c|d", ".+ ^a$")), valuetype = "regex")
#>                                      
#>  [text1, 2:3]       a | b c | a b d e
#>  [text1, 3:4]     a b | c a | b d e  
#>  [text1, 5:6] a b c a | b d | e
```

For **part two**, you can use wildcard matching to match anything, which is easiest using the default "glob" match:

```r
kwic("this is a test", pattern = phrase("* * *"))
#>                                      
#>  [text1, 1:3]      | this is a | test
#>  [text1, 2:4] this | is a test |

kwic("this is a test", pattern = phrase("* *"))
#>                                         
#>  [text1, 1:2]         | this is | a test
#>  [text1, 2:3]    this |  is a   | test  
#>  [text1, 3:4] this is | a test  |
```

Note finally that it *is* possible to include whitespace as part of a pattern match, but only if you have tokens that include whitespace.  This would be true if you were to pass through the `remove_separators = FALSE` argument to the `tokens()` call via `...` (see `?kwic`), or if you created tokens in some other way to ensure they contain whitespace.

```r
as.tokens(list(d1 = c("a b", " ", "c"))) %>%
  kwic(phrase("\\s"), valuetype = "regex")
#>                        
#>  [d1, 1]     | a b |  c
#>  [d1, 2] a b |     | c
```

There, the "a b" that is displayed is actually the single token "a b", not the sequence of tokens "a", "b".  The blank on the second line is the " " token.

<sup>Created on 2020-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that was a very helpful overview of the possibilities!